# What is the difference between simple imagesearch command and using it with coordmode in Autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to know the difference between using simple `imagesearch` command and using it with `coordmode`.

What difference does it really make when we use it with `coordmode`?

Please elaborate and provide a few examples also.

Comment: I am having some trouble understanding what it is you want to do. Could you attempt to clarify a bit? What exactly is the input data fo your macro, and what do you want the end result to be?

Answer (score 0):

Excerpted from [Autohotkey docs](http://autohotkey.free.fr/docs/commands/CoordMode.htm):

> Coordmode sets the coordinate mode for various commands to be relative to either the active window or the screen.
>
> If this command is not used, all commands except those documented otherwise (e.g. WinMove and InputBox) use coordinates that are relative to the active window.
>
> Every newly launched thread (such as a hotkey, custom menu item, or timed subroutine), starts off fresh with the default setting for this command. That default may be changed by using this command in the auto-execute section (top part of the script).

Coordmode uses two parameters:

[image: parameters]